# How to align text in the Button widget in 'customtkinter'

Tags: python, tkinter, text, alignment, customtkinter

I have been struggling with this for hours, I searched for ages but still no clue.
I want the text in the CTkButton to **align to the left** like this [TKINTER SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCGbF.png) , rather **than the center** [CUSTOM TKINTER SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5BHF.png). The thing is, in tkinter there is an option called `anchor='w'` but there is not in customtkinter .

> Tkinter Code

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
button = Button(root,width=30,anchor='w',text='tkinter button')
button.pack()
root.mainloop(
```

> Customtkinter

```
from customtkinter import *
root = CTk()
button = CTkButton(root,width=30,text='customtkinter button')
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: please share your codes here so we could help..tq

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MrNoob I have added some code snippets to clarify the situation as you can see above

Comment: Have you asked the developer of custom tkinter, or examined the source code?

Comment: The text is a tkinter `Label` widget inside the customtkinter widget using `.grid()` as the layout manager, so try `button.text_label.grid(sticky='w')`. Note that you need to make the button wider, for example `width=200` (unit is in pixels for customtkinter widget), to see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough space to see the alignment. That I think :)
Try width = 200

```
from customtkinter import *
root = CTk()
button = CTkButton(root, width=200, anchor='w', text='customtkinter button')
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Op want align to left. `button.pack(side=LEFT)`

Comment: use grid with sticky='w